# How to speed up curl?

Tags: curl

I wrote a script on my Debian machine to read a file of URLs and output the HTTP Status code for each one:

```bsh
...
while read url
do
    urlstatus=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --insecure --write-out '%{http_code} ; %{redirect_url}' "$url")
    ...
done < $1
```

With a file of 100 URLs it's OK, but with a huge file with more than 1000 URLs, my script becomes very slow!

I've tried several 'tips' found on SO : set KeepAlive with `-H 'Keep-Alive: 500'`, define GoogleBot as User Agent with `--user-agent 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'` and define a connection time out with `--connect-timeout 1` but nothing!

Comment: Of course it is slow, you're downloading 1000 URLs. What do you want to change here? Are you trying to speed up each download or do you want to run multiple `curl` commands in paralel?

Comment: Similar: https://superuser.com/q/1594171/432690

Comment: @terdon I thought `-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'` is used to download only the header and avoid downloading the whole page ! All I need is HTTP status code and - in case of redirection - the new URL

Comment: @Sami: `--head` or `-I` will cause it to download only the header.

Comment: @Sami I'm not sure, but even if it is, you still need to open the connection to each of them. That takes time.

Comment: @terdon I confirm : `--head` argument did nothing :(

Comment: Why ``--keepalive 60`` did nothing ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run them in parallel you can use GNU parallel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1

status_func () {
    local _url="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
    local _urlstatus
    _urlstatus=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --insecure --write-out '%{http_code} ; %{redirect_url}' "$_url")
    printf 'Status: %s\n' "$_urlstatus"
}

export -f status_func

cat "$file" | parallel -j20 status_func
```

The -j option will set the maximum number of simultaneous jobs, the default is the number of threads on your system but you may need to tweak that number for optimal results.

Note you will have to add your commands into a function (or alternatively a separate script altogether) and export that function so that parallel knows about it.

If you were to put your commands into a standalone script than you could just run it from the command line like:

```
cat "$file" | parallel -j20 ./my_script.sh
```

Note this script should expect only a single URL sent via stdin.

---

Alternatively if you cannot use GNU parallel but still want to run multiple jobs at once you could just execute them as background jobs but will most likely want to limit the number of simultaneous processes.  That can be accomplished with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1

max_bg_procs () {
    local max_number=$((0 + ${1:-0}))
    while :; do
        local current_number=$(jobs -pr | wc -l)
        if [[ $current_number -lt $max_number ]]; then
            break
        fi
        sleep 2
    done
}

status_func () {
    local _url="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
    local _urlstatus
    _urlstatus=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --insecure --write-out '%{http_code} ; %{redirect_url}' "$_url")
    printf 'Status: %s\n' "$_urlstatus"
}

while IFS= read -rd url; do
    max_bg_procs 20
    status_func "$url" &
done < "$file"
```

Comment: `cat "$file" | parallel -j20 ./my_script.sh` seems very easy, but will this correctly "split" the file ? I mean will each process retrieve different set of urls from the source file ?

Comment: @Sami: In that example each process will receive exactly **one** url from the source file.  That is why the script must only be programmed to act on a single URL at a time.  You could configure parallel to send the URLs in batches but it wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `xargs -P0`

```bsh
seq 100 | xargs -I@ echo 'https://example.com?@' > urls.txt
cat urls.txt | xargs -P0 -n1 curl
```

## How fast?

Without `-P0`:

```bsh
time sh -c 'cat urls.txt | xargs -n1 curl'
```

```
real    0m 59.79s
user    0m 1.64s
sys     0m 0.99s
```

With `-P0`:

```bsh
time sh -c 'cat urls.txt | xargs -P0 -n1 curl'
```

```
real    0m 0.76s
user    0m 1.26s
sys     0m 0.82s
```

Quoted from `man xargs`:

> -P maxprocs
>
> Parallel mode: run at most maxprocs invocations of utility at once.  If maxprocs is set to 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `-Z`

Another potential solution depending on your use case is the `-Z` flag.  This is useful when providing multiple URLs to `curl` or when having curl automate things like pagination by specifying a `curl` specific syntax to work on a range.

The documentation for the `-Z` flag is https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-Z

The documentation for `curl` specific range syntax is in https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html and ^F 'Globbing'.

`curl -Z $(cat urls.txt | xargs)`